# Illustrator losing most recent handle when I continue path after editing previous handles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, typography, pen-tool, lettering

In Illustrator, when creating a path (such as for lettering), how do you go back and adjust handles of anchor points before the current on, and then continue from where you left off without losing the most recent handle?

He manages to do it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgbtJM1Zuks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not clear about what it is you're asking and the video link doesn't really aid in explaining either.

You can hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> (Mac) or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Win) to temporarily access the last Selection Tool used.

I suspect what you are seeing is work with the pen tool, hold down the key above and use the Direct Selection Tool to move something, then let go of the key and you're back to the Pen Tool. All without loosing the last active anchor.

You can also use the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** in the same fashion, you merely hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key on the Mac to access that tool (Sorry I don't know if the Windows right-click is the equivalent in this case. In most instances it is, but this seems like it might not be.)

Comment: Holding "command" fixed it. Thanks a bunch!